# How to enable zsh 5.0 highlighting and colouring of the command line?

Tags: zsh

ZSH 5.0 support highlighting and colouring of the command line, but how to enable it?
I search with google, but no answer.

Comment: What highlighting? Zsh supports it (actually support was added earlier then in 5.0), but it ships with no highlighting scripts by default. Prompt colouring is different and has nothing to do with this feature, it just got more readable syntax (again, in 4.3* version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, zsh highlights the whole regular command text with one colour and sets different colours for non-regular texts: incremental search match, region being marked, special characters and automatically removed suffixes. This all is controlled by `zle_highlight` variable, more data can be seen in `Character Highlighting` section in `man zshzle`. Additionally `region_highlight` variable can be used to highlight arbitrary region on the command-line, it is described in `USER-DEFINED WIDGETS` section in the same manual. To make the last one useful you need to find a zsh plugin or write out your own.

Answer (score 7):

This message is a little old, but I wanted to let you know I had a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981928/syntax-highlighting-at-command-line-as-i-type) with a similar question.  One answer came back that there's a plugin [`zsh-syntax-highlighting`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) that will allow you to do this.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) instead. It is extremely easy to use.